# Creating custom SeekBar with a triangle shape background

Tags: android

I am trying to create a custom SeekBar with a triangle shape background. There is no thumb icon. Below are some images of what I want to achieve

[image: Empty SeekBar]

[image: 3/4 Full SeekBar]

[image: Full SeekBar]

Below is my code so far

Res/Drawable/segment_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#FF5e8ea3"
                    android:centerColor="#FF32a0d2"
                    android:centerY="0.1"
                    android:endColor="#FF13729e"
                    android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Res/Drawable/segment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/slider"
            android:dither="true"
         />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80028ac8"
                    android:centerColor="#80127fb1"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a004638f"
                    android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/segment_bg"
    />
</layer-list>
```

activity.xml

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/frequency_slider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:max="20"
    android:progress="0"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/segment"
/>
```

The 9-patch image used is

[image: 9 Patch Slider]

The result looks like this

[image: Incorrect SeekBar]

My questions are how do I have the seekbar cater for the triangle shape? Then how do I remove the thumb icon, one isn't needed.

Thanks

Comment: That image can't be put in a nine patch image if you want to keep it's current state. Did you solved this problem?

Comment: @Luksprog I have temporarialy resolved the problem by using a simple PNG instead of a 9-patch. However, this doesn't scale when using a tablet.

Comment: If that is the exact image you're trying to do and a `SeekBar` isn't an absolute requirement(especially if you don't set a thumb drawable for the user to see) you could probably create a custom view and draw that shape using a `Path`. With that path you could make it scale very well and with a clever touch event handling you'll obtain the behavior of a `Seekbar`.

Comment: I have avoided this problem for a few days. I will try to tackle it agin using Path. Thanks.